# how cmd rename sequence number and dirname

Tags: regex, linux, awk, rename

goodevening, we not native english.
we try linux cmd rename many file or directory.
exsample
`time\1.ext
test\newname.ext
read\test.ext
what\abc.ext`

want result hear.
`time\01-time.ext
test\02-test.ext
read\03-read.ext
what\04-what.ext`
is sequence number and dirname.

we tryed other question site post cord.
but dose'nt result.

`find "$PWD" -name "[0-9][0-9].md" -exec bash -c ' DIR=$( dirname "{}"  ); FILE=$( firename "{}"  ); echo "{}" "$DIR"/"-${DIR##*/}".md  ' \;`

`ls *.* | awk '{ printf "mv %s dirname-%03d.md\n", $0, NR }'`

how this file rename use cmd?
we want result is unnamed dile & directory.
png,txt,md,many ext.
we tryed cmd "*.*" "[0-9][0-9]" is regular expression.

Comment: What new name should be used if there are more than 100 files? Could there become `01-time.ext` and `02-time.pdf`?

Comment: well, if rename more than 100 files number is.  
we use `[001]` from `[01]`, in that case.  
and mixed extfiles inside directory.  
your right, we use `01-time.ext and 02-time.pdf and 03-time.png` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if you have a requirement to use `awk` or any other specific command. Here is a rather simplistic way to loop over the files and rename them. When you are confident that the correct renaming will occur, remove the `echo` from the `mv` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1

for fn in $(find . -name "*.ext" -o -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.png")
do
    filename=$(basename $fn)
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    dn=$(dirname $fn)
    dp=$(basename $dn)
    thiscount=$(printf "%03d" $count)

    echo mv $fn $dn/$thiscount-$dp.$extension

    count=$((count+1))
done
```

Comment: thanks,we try rename test and create servicemenu in kde dolphin. we wish rename success. so, sorry, solved is after success rename. later.

Comment: sorry we change control file method. but thanks you help.